# LoadRunner VS CA ApplicationTest(LISA) on Performance testing

Tags: performance, loadrunner, ca-lisa

What are your thoughts on LoadRunner and CA AppTest(LISA) on Performance testing? Why would someone use LoadRunner instead of CA AppTest or the other way around? Help me to make a decision as a customer to choose which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

Write down your requirements.  Do not use requirements handed to you from either vendor.  Make sure you include requirements on environment, types of applications to test, monitoring in your environment of your types of hosts and services, reporting and analysis.

Then, with your requirements in hand, construct a set of tasks to measure against the requirements.

Next, go to market and hire for one week experts in both tools.  Here is where you will want to pay for the best so you can match each tool against it's best use with an optimal user.

Schedule the use of a demo license of the tools for that one week.

None of us know your organization's infrastructure requirements, the skills of your team, your reporting and analysis needs, even whether you have the skills in house to use either tool effectively.  You need to come up with specific, measurable, attainable, realistic and time-based (SMART) requirements for your evaluation of both tools.

And, by the way, asking for "which is better..." or "a review of..." tends to not go well in public forums where everyone else's requirements are distinct from your own.

> Use Bob's homegrown Get & Put engine.  It beats all of the tools in the universe and Bob is super cool

See, it could get really bad......